# Problem with HDN_ENDTRACK when resizing a list column

Tags: c++, mfc, event-handling, clistctrl

I am having a bit of a problem when handling a HDN_ENDTRACKW message for a custom class which derives from CListCtrl .

Essentially, it seem that when this message is sent, the actual value which stores the width of the column is not updated until after my handling code has been executed.

The code inside the handle simply instructs a progress bar to resize, to fill the width of the resized column.
The code:

```
void ProgListCtrl::OnEndTrack(NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult)
{
 int width = ListView_GetColumnWidth(GetSafeHwnd(), m_nProgressColumn);
 ResizeProgressbar();
}
```

The ListView_GetColumnWidth is there just to help with debugging at the moment.

The default value for the particular column I am changing is 150, when i resize the column in the UI, this method is called but the width stays at the same 150, the progress bar does not resize. Only when a column is resized again does the width value now reflect the value of the column after the first resize, the ResizeProgressBar method then correctly changes the progbar size to fill the column it is in. This is continuous, the width value always seems to be one step behind the actual value.

I would apreciate any help. Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the information that `HDN_ENDTRACK` itself provides to you, ie:

```
void ProgListCtrl::OnEndTrack(NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult)
{
    NMHEADER *pHdr = (NMHEADER*) pNMHDR;
    if ((pHdr->iItem == m_nProgressColumn) &&
        (pHdr->pitem) &&
        (pHdr->pitem->mask & HDI_WIDTH))
    {
        int width = pHdr->pitem->cxy;
        ResizeProgressbar();
    }
}
```

Alternatively, look at the `HDN_ITEMCHANGING` and `HDN_ITEMCHANGED` notifications instead of `HDN_ENDTRACK`.

Comment: HDN_ITEMCHANGED worked! It did not require me to change anything more than the message map. Thanks for your help!

Comment: NMHEADER and NMHDR are two different structures. How can you cast one to another? NMHDR specifies no casting operator.

Comment: @SahilSingh All structs delivered via `WM_NOTIFY` start with a `NMHDR` field. This is stated in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775583.aspx): "*`lParam`: A pointer to an `NMHDR` structure that contains the notification code and additional information. **For some notification messages, this parameter points to a larger structure that has the `NMHDR` structure as its first member**.*" A pointer to the first member is also a pointer to the whole struct, so the type-cast is safe as long as you use the correct struct type for the cast.

Comment: @SahilSingh `HDN_ENDTRACK` sends a pointer to the `NMHDR` member of a `NMHEADER` struct, per the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775273.aspx): "*`lParam`:

**A pointer to an `NMHEADER` structure** that contains information about the header control and the item whose divider was dragged.*"