# How to catch a CListCtrl column width change event?

Tags: c++, mfc, clistctrl

How can I catch `CListCtrl` column width change event in MFC? I believe there should be an `OnNotify()` event but I am note sure about various values and the parameters to use for message map and the event itself.

Please note that a `CListCtrl` column width can change by dragging the column divider or by double clicking on the header row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the key is to understand that there is a difference in the listcontrol itself, and the header control. By using the GetHeaderCtrl() member function of the listcontrol you can get to the header control. For working with the header control, see this article: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/headerctrl.aspx?display=Mobile#Anchor-Handlin-41471
Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you expand the answer by describing how to implement one of the tracking events of the header control?

Comment: I don't have a working example at my fingertips, but I think the article that I referred to describes the usage pretty well. Alternatively you could have a look at this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164140.aspx
What is it exactly that is unclear to you or causing you troubles?

Comment: I know this question is really old, but I have been looking for an answer all day and found a good clue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426665/problem-with-hdn-endtrack-when-resizing-a-list-column